# What should be the URI for the WCF HTTP Post?

Tags: .net, wcf

I am coding a WCF HTTP POST, the following is the service contract, what should I do about be URI used to consume the service?

```
  [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/JsonData",
                RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "POST")]
        bool SendData(JsonString JsonImage);

        // TODO: Add your service operations here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your WCF service most likely has a configuration file which defines the Service Host binding, behavior and endpoint elements.  As such, the URL should be the combination of the service base address and the UriTemplate.  The following configuration file snippets provide a reference sample from one of our wcf https rest services:

```
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="RestBinding">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
```

…

```
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="DefaultServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceCredentials>
           …
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
```

…

```
 <service name="TestRest">
    <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="RestBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="RestBinding" name="RestServiceEndpoint"
      contract="Test.Rest.Interface" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://domain.name.here:18100/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
```

As such, the URL will be:
http://domain.name.here:18100/JsonData

Regards,